# Sending an elem.click() if button pressed in a while loop combined with a for loop

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

```
import pyautogui as py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import keyboard
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcel9QTPx_g&list=RDpcel9QTPx_g&start_radio=1&t=11&ab_channel=%E5%BE%AE%E7%B3%96%E9%80%A2')
elem = driver.find_elements_by_id('video-title')
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('`'):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[29]/div[2]/div[1]/button'.click()
    for x in elem:
        elem.click()
        keyboard.wait('f4)
```

So i am trying to automate iterating through a bunch of songs playlist in selenium using python. I am trying make the code so when i pressed `, the video will pause and if i pressed f4 the code will skips to the next iteration. The f4 function is working just fine but the code inside the while loop isn't. Is it because when the code runs, when it gets to the for loop it won't get access to the while loop anymore? If you guys have any ideas or want to simplify my code feel free to answer!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem but the line `elem.click()` seems wrong to me. `elem` is a list variable and doesn't change in the for loop. Shouldn't it be `x.click()`?

Comment: keyboard.wait('f4)?  keyboard.wait('f4')?

Comment: yea turns out i made a mistake in the ' part, but wasn't in my code, only when i pasted the code here. the elem.click() is wrong too, turns out i pasted the wrong code. I exchanged the while loop with the for loop and the code works.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyautogui as py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import keyboard
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcel9QTPx_g&list=RDpcel9QTPx_g&start_radio=1&t=11&ab_channel=%E5%BE%AE%E7%B3%96%E9%80%A2')
elem = driver.find_elements_by_id('video-title')
for x in elem:
    x.click()
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('f12'):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[29]/div[2]/div[1]/button').click()
            keyboard.wait('f12')
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[29]/div[2]/div[1]/button').click()
        if keyboard.is_pressed('f4'):
            break
    keyboard.wait('f4')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest you to use another key instead of f12 because it will disrupt your code when you are running it from chrome, it will open developer mode!